# Looping through SQL records with asp

Tags: sql-server, loops, asp-classic

I need to display an XML output which outputs multiple line items based on a request that passes one record number for a search.

For example, the request passes a record number for record 'ABC123' to search for.

The response looks up the record by the record number and returns some fields:

```
<RecordNo>ABC123</ReocrdNo>
<LineNo>1</LineNo>
<Item>Good record</Item>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
<Price>5.00</Price>
```

However, one record may have multiple line items, so something like

```
<RecordNo>ABC123</ReocrdNo>
<LineNo>1</LineNo>
<Item>Good record</Item>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
<Price>5.00</Price>

<RecordNo>ABC123</ReocrdNo>
<LineNo>2</LineNo>
<Item>Best record</Item>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
<Price>6.00</Price>
```

The table structure basically has a main table with the record number, and then connects to multiple detail records in a detail table for that one main record. I know I need to use some sort of looping. The XML output is done on the asp page by:

```
Set nodeTierRecordNum = CreateNode(nodeTierLine, "Quantity", "")
nodeTierRecordNum.text = cmdGetRecord.Parameters("@quantity").Value
```

And on the SQL side:

```
SET @quantity = (SELECT qty FROM record_details WHERE record_id = @record_id_passed_in)
```

But this will return multiple values, because there are multiple records (lines) for this record.

```
qty
1
1
```

How do I achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Required group by as per requirement:

```
SET @quantity = (SELECT sum(qty) FROM record_details WHERE record_id = @record_id_passed_in
group by Item)
```

And another one is XML output:

```
SELECT record_id, sum(qty) as qty FROM record_details
 WHERE record_id = @record_id_passed_in
 group by record_id
 for XML auto
```